# Why doesn't my launchpad login work on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, launchpad

I keep getting the message:

Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

No OpenID endpoint found.

I'm running a fairly old Ubuntu and Firefox with JavaScript enabled.

Comment: It should resolve automatically. I suggest to wait.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use your Launchpad username, not your email. The OpenID URL must look like https://launchpad.net/~youruser and not like https://launchpad.net/~youruser@email.com.